# Codingbat challenge: sameEnds

Tags: java, string, substring, matching

Given task [sameEnds](https://codingbat.com/prob/p131516) from CodingBat:

Given a string, return the longest substring that appears at both the beginning and end of the string without overlapping. For example, sameEnds("abXab") is "ab".

```
sameEnds("abXYab") → "ab"
sameEnds("xx") → "x"
sameEnds("xxx") → "x"
```

My solution passes all the tests except one^:

```
public String sameEnds(String string) {
  String substringFront = "";
  String substringEnd = "";
  String longestSubstring = "";
  
  for (int i = 1; i < string.length() - 1; i++) {
    substringFront = string.substring(0, i);
    substringEnd = string.substring(i);
    
    if (substringEnd.contains(substringFront)) {
      longestSubstring = substringFront;
    }
  }
  
  return longestSubstring;
}
```

What is the problem here? How could I fix it?

[image]

Comment: For input with a length of 2 you will not enter the loop because `i < string.length() - 1` is not true. Change that to `i <= string.length() - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution passes all tests:

```
public String sameEnds(String string) {
  String substringFront = "";
  String substringEnd = "";
  String longestSubstring = "";
  
  for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++) {
    substringFront = string.substring(0, i);
    substringEnd = string.substring(i);
    
    if (substringEnd.contains(substringFront)) {
      longestSubstring = substringFront;
    }
  }
  
  return longestSubstring;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the technical issues that @Dan and others have aptly pointed out, I want to highlight the issue of unnecessary complexity, which in many cases leads to such logical errors.

Given this, and considering that this is a challenge, I would prefer a minimalistic approach, like the one below, which is self-explanatory and hence simple to comprehend and debug.

```
public String sameEnds(String string) {
  int middle = string.length() / 2;
  for (int i = middle; i >= 0; i--) {
    String left = string.substring(0, i);
    if (string.endsWith(left)) {
      return left;
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of problems within your code:

- You stop iterating before reaching the last character, instead of iterating till length/2 included (you need to check the beginning and end without overlapping so no need to iterate till the end or almost).
- You `substringEnd` should start from the right side, so it should look like `string.substring(string.length() - i);`.

Here is a fixed implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listTest = List.of("abXYab", "xx", "xxx", "xxxx", "javaXYZjava", "javajava", "Hello! and Hello!", "x", "", "abcd", "mymmy");
    String substringFront, substringEnd, longestMatch;
    for (String string : listTest) {
        longestMatch = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= string.length() / 2; i++) {
            substringFront = string.substring(0, i);
            substringEnd = string.substring(string.length() - i);

            if (substringEnd.equals(substringFront) && substringEnd.length() > longestMatch.length()) {
                longestMatch = substringEnd;
            }
        }

        if (!listTest.equals("")) {
            System.out.printf("%s => %s%n", string, longestMatch);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s => null%n", string);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a link to test the code above:

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/rEO

However, to make it more concise you could use a regex which uses a capturing group with a greedy quantifier to match at the beginning of the string and make sure that what has been captured at the beginning matches also at the end.

```
^(.+)(.*)\1$
```

Here is a link to test the regex:

https://regex101.com/r/cgowDQ/1

This could be written in Java like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listTest = List.of("abXYab", "xx", "xxx", "xxxx", "javaXYZjava", "javajava", "Hello! and Hello!", "x", "", "abcd", "mymmy");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.+)(.*)\\1$");
    Matcher matcher;
    for (String s : listTest) {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.printf("%s => %s%n", s, matcher.group(1));
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s => null%n", s);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can test the code above:

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/rEK

Answer (score 1):

Iterate till the last element in the String, changing the loop condition fixes the problem.

```
for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++)
```

Comment: You can iterate to half the length of string too. As the problem says it does not want overlapping characters. i.e.  `i <= string.length()/2`